# MakerDAO vs AAVE solidity architecture design

Tags: architecture, dependencies, ethereum, solidity, decoupling

I have an interesting solidity architecture question. I noticed that the DAI contracts [makerdao](https://github.com/makerdao/dss/tree/master/src) are using only 'interface' style to communicate between contracts, avoiding absolutely using the 'import' keyword. From the other point of view, [aave](https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/tree/master/contracts) contracts are over using 'imports' between contracts. My question is, what would be the advantages and disadvantages between the two approaches ?
thanks in advance !

Comment: In fact I found a similar question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8615/child-contract-vs-struct/8620), and initially maybe DAI team decided to have multiple contracts to avoid the TheDAO tragedy, if so, the question for AAVE design decisions remains.